# invisible columns in oracle 12c view

Tags: oracle12c

One of the topics on the Oracle 1Z0-047 sql expert exam is "Create simple and complex views with visible/invisible columns". I can create tables with invisible columns, I can create a view containing those invisible columns, but I cannot find the syntax to make those columns invisible in the resulting view. Oracle documentation mentions visible/invisible in the Database SQL language reference `"Create View"` page but gives no specific example and my attempt at following their squiggly diagram failed:

```
create or replace view jl_book_author as  
    select title, b.isbn isbn invisible, lname, fname  
        from jl_books b  
            join jl_bookauthor a on b.isbn = a.isbn  
            join jl_author r on a.authorid = r.authorid  
         order by title, lname, fname;  
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Any idea how to do make a column of a view invisible and why I would want to do this other than to pass the exam?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Valorax, looks much better! Can you explain how you did it? I put indents with 4 spaces in the original, just as the instructions said, but the final output had no indents. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. The only way to specify `"INVISIBLE"` is if you're using column aliases in the view. The aliases, constraints and `INVISIBLE/VISIBLE` modifiers need to be in parenthesis between the view name and keyword "AS".

```
create or replace view jl_book_author (tl, bn INVISIBLE, al, af) as  
    select title, b.isbn, lname, fname  
        from jl_books b  
            join jl_bookauthor a on b.isbn = a.isbn  
            join jl_author r on a.authorid = r.authorid  
         order by title, lname, fname;
```

Answer (score 1):

> "why I would want to do this other than to pass the exam?"

You use the `INVISIBLE` clause, as stated in the Oracle SQL Reference [`CREATE TABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402), to add columns to any table, without having code that includes wildcard `SELECT *` statements add to it haphazardly.

Therefore very useful for adding columns to tables that you wouldnt want *legacy* code to casually manipulate.

For a fuller explanation and examples see the article [ASK TOM: technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-may/o34asktom-2162246.html) from the  **MAY/JUNE 2014** edition of Oracle Magazine.